# uiautomatorviewer batch file is not opening

Tags: android, appium

"uiautomatorviewer" batch file is not opening and give the error of environmental variables path is not set even I set the path variables.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and what was the error message.

Comment: i set the path variables and also installed the 9th version of java but the error message is remain same.

Comment: when i double click on "uiautomatorviewer" the command screen open and then close with this message " 
ERROR: No suitable Java found.......

Answer (score 9):

if you have installed JDK 10 , Change it to JDK 8, Download from the below location

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

**Set below  new System Environment variables:**

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\asaini75\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

**Add below directories to your Path system evnironment variable**

```
PATH= %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;
%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin;
%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

**To check if everything is setup correctly , Use below command***

sdkmanager --list
if you see some local repositories are getting download, That means everything is set correctly, Now go and click on "uiautomatorviewer" , It will open perfectly fine

Comment: Showing this error 
>sdkmanager --list

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I have found a solution with no need to downgrade to Java 8 from your current latest Java set up.

In the Android set up itself, there is a provision for JRE to run virtual machine for uiautomatorviewer.

You can check you Android Installation path for JRE: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin

Add this JRE path in your system path Environment Variable and done.

This has fixed my problem with Java is installed as version 11.

Comment: Thanks. This solution solved my problem without downgrading my Java version.

Comment: Can you spell out EXACTLY what someone would have to do?

Answer (score 4):

This happens because of incompatible versions of java. uiautomatorviewer requires java 8 and if you've java version above 8 (for example in my case it's java 12) so it will fail to start.

There is a hack to run uiautomatorviewer without downgrading java version.
Android studio already comes with a jre which is compatible with uiautomatorviewer.

Simply, we have to temporarily set **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to point to **C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre**

In command prompt, type the following commands:

```
cd C:\Users\sayyed\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
uiautomatorviewer.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arpan Saini

thank you. your answer has helped me.

**1. first configuration** gets error

a. jdk 12

b. android sdk 9.0

Set below new System Environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=D:\winusr\Java\openjdk-12.0.1_windows-x64_bin\jdk-12.0.1
ANDROID_HOME=D:\winusr\google\android_sdk\api_28_android_9.0_pie
```

and forward append Path System Environment variable:

```
PATH= %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

run uiautomatorviewer.bat, returns error as follows:

D:\winusr\google\android_sdk\api_28_android_9.0_pie\tools\bin
λ uiautomatorviewer.bat
-Djava.ext.dirs=..\lib\x86_64;..\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

**2. second configuration** gets ok

a. jdk 8.0

b. android sdk 9.0

Set below new System Environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=D:\winusr\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
ANDROID_HOME=D:\winusr\google\android_sdk\api_28_android_9.0_pie
```

and forward append Path System Environment variable:

```
PATH= %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;
```

**reopen cmd.exe**, and run uiautomatorviewer.bat, gets ok:

D:\winusr\google\android_sdk\api_28_android_9.0_pie\tools\bin
λ uiautomatorviewer.bat

[first configuration, gets error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5hky.png)

[second configuration, gets ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zXdd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just add below environment variables in system settings as:

`_JAVA_OPTIONS` with value `-Xmx256M`

and you are good to go with any Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to previous commenters, aspecially to [Salman Momin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46908523/uiautomatorviewer-batch-file-is-not-opening/61627702#61627702).
In my case I have Java 11.
I added first line:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
```

into my C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin\uiautomatorviewer.bat

And it is a simpliest solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above.
Only downgrade from 11 -> 8.

Answer (score 0):

Just install jdk-8u321-windows-x64.exe , nothing else only this is working ,newer version have issues

Answer (score -1):

As a solution for this case, I had set Path to JRE of **Android Studio**  in file "uiautomatorviewer.bat", can you find it in "folder->android-sdks->Tools->uiautomatorviewer.bat".

Example of my config in this file.

```
...
rem Check we have a valid Java.exe in the path.
set java_exe=C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe
call ..\lib\find_java.bat
if not defined java_exe goto :EOF
...
```

Comment: Please answer in English.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me. While I was working on `Linux`, I changed `javaCmd="java"` to `javaCmd=<path-to>/android-studio/jre/bin/java`.

Answer (score -3):

You can start `uiautomator` using double click on `uiautomatorviewer.bat`.

Go to SDK

> folder->android-sdks->Tools->uiautomatorviewer.bat

`uiautomator` window will appear after clicking on batch file

ex .

> C:\Users\abc\android-sdks\tools